# XSL for sorting on a node in XML

Tags: xml, vba, xslt, ms-word

I have an xml file from an outside source.  I'm attempting to bring it into VBA and create a word document out of it.  It all works fine except I cannot get the sort to work using XSL (or without it for that matter).

I've googled and chat gpt'ed a bunch of solutions, but none of them are working for me.  I'm trying to sort on "Sort Order", which is tagged in the xml as a custom field.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<project>
    <projectId>10010</projectId>
    <projectKey>NBSVV</projectKey>
    <exportDate>2023-06-08 13:50:44 UTC</exportDate>
    <folders>
        <folder fullPath="Folderpath" index="2"/>
    </folders>
    <testCases>
        <testCase id="51024947" key="NBSVV-T88">
            <attachments/>
            <confluencePageLinks/>
            <createdBy>bill</createdBy>
            <createdOn>2022-10-31 03:10:46 UTC</createdOn>
            <customFields>
                <customField name="Sort Order" type="NUMBER">
                    <value><![CDATA[15]]></value>
                </customField>
                <customField name="Subsystem" type="SINGLE_CHOICE_SELECT_LIST">
                    <value><![CDATA[Interlocks]]></value>
                </customField>
            </customFields>
            <name><![CDATA[Interlocks - HEBL Vacuum Pressures High]]></name>
        </testCase>
        <testCase id="51024970" key="NBSVV-T89">
            <attachments/>
            <confluencePageLinks/>
            <createdBy>bob</createdBy>
            <createdOn>2022-10-31 03:15:07 UTC</createdOn>
            <customFields>
                <customField name="Sort Order" type="NUMBER">
                    <value><![CDATA[40]]></value>
                </customField>
                <customField name="Subsystem" type="SINGLE_CHOICE_SELECT_LIST">
                    <value><![CDATA[Interlocks]]></value>
                </customField>
            </customFields>
            <name><![CDATA[Interlocks - Tandem Vacuum Pressures Out of Tolerance]]></name>
        </testCase>
        <testCase id="51024975" key="NBSVV-T90">
            <attachments/>
            <confluencePageLinks/>
            <createdBy>jane</createdBy>
            <createdOn>2022-10-31 03:16:14 UTC</createdOn>
            <customFields>
                <customField name="Sort Order" type="NUMBER">
                    <value><![CDATA[30]]></value>
                </customField>
                <customField name="Subsystem" type="SINGLE_CHOICE_SELECT_LIST">
                    <value><![CDATA[Interlocks]]></value>
                </customField>
            </customFields>
            <name><![CDATA[Interlocks - Target Vacuum Pressures High]]></name>
        </testCase>
        <testCase id="86486160" key="NBSVV-T52">
            <attachments/>
            <confluencePageLinks/>
            <createdBy>joe</createdBy>
            <createdOn>2023-05-11 19:14:20 UTC</createdOn>
            <customFields>
                <customField name="Sort Order" type="NUMBER">
                    <value><![CDATA[10]]></value>
                </customField>
                <customField name="Subsystem" type="SINGLE_CHOICE_SELECT_LIST">
                    <value><![CDATA[Interlocks]]></value>
                </customField>
            </customFields>
            <name><![CDATA[Interlocks - Gate Valve Positions]]></name>
        </testCase>
    </testCases>
</project>
```

The XSL I'm trying to use to sort it.  I've tried using Sort Order instead of customField[0], etc

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//project/testCases">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="testCase">
<xsl:sort select="testCase/customFields/customField[1]" data-type="number"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
<xsl:sort select="testCase/customFields/customField[1]" data-type="number"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:sort select="customFields/customField[1]" data-type="number"/>
```

or even better, to:

```
<xsl:sort select="customFields/customField[@name='Sort Order']/value" data-type="number"/>
```

What you have is looking for a `testCase` element that is a child of `testCase` - and not finding anything.